# Getting TF-IDF values from index

Tags: java, indexing, lucene, information-retrieval, tf-idf

The below code is for getting tf-idf value from indexes. But I get an error while running it, on the line with `Correct_ME`.

Using Lucene 4.8.

DocIndexing.java

```
    public class DocIndexing {
    private DocIndexing() {}

  /** Index all text files under a directory.
     * @param args
     * @throws java.io.IOException */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   String usage = "java org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexFiles"
                 + " [-index INDEX_PATH] [-docs DOCS_PATH] [-update]\n\n"
                 + "This indexes the documents in DOCS_PATH, creating a Lucene index"
                 + "in INDEX_PATH that can be searched with Searching";

    String indexPath = "C:/Users/dell/Documents/NetBeansProjects/IndexingSearching/Index";

    String docsPath = "C:/Users/dell/Documents/NetBeansProjects/IndexingSearching/ToBeIndexed"; 
    boolean create = true;
    for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++) {
      if (null != args[i]) switch (args[i]) {
           case "-index":
               indexPath = args[i+1];
               i++;
               break;
           case "-docs":
               docsPath = args[i+1];
               i++;
               break;
           case "-update":
               create = false;
               break;
       }
    }

    if (docsPath == null) {
      System.err.println("Usage: " + usage);
      System.exit(1);
    }

    final File docDir = new File(docsPath);
    if (!docDir.canRead() && !docDir.isDirectory() &&
            !docDir.isHidden() &&
            !docDir.exists()) {
      System.out.println("Document directory '" +docDir.getAbsolutePath()+ "' does not exist or is not readable, please check the path");
      System.exit(1);
    }

    Date start = new Date();
    try {
      System.out.println("Indexing to directory '" + indexPath + "'...");

      Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File(indexPath));

       Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_48);
       //Filter filter = new PorterStemFilter();
       IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_48, analyzer);

      if (create) {

        iwc.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE);
      } else {
        // Add new documents to an existing index:
        iwc.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
      }


        try ( 
                IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, iwc)) {

            indexDocs(writer, docDir);
        }

      Date end = new Date();
      System.out.println(end.getTime() - start.getTime() + " total milliseconds");

    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println(" caught a " + e.getClass() +
       "\n with message: " + e.getMessage());
    }
     Tf_Idf tfidf = new Tf_Idf();


     String field = null,term = null;

     tfidf.scoreCalculator(field, term);




  }


   /*  
   * @param writer Writer to the index where the given file/dir info will be stored
   * @param file The file to index, or the directory to recurse into to find files to index
   * @throws IOException If there is a low-level I/O error
   */
  static void indexDocs(IndexWriter writer, File file)
    throws IOException {
    // do not try to index files that cannot be read
    if (file.canRead()) {
      if (file.isDirectory()) {
        String[] files = file.list();
        // an IO error could occur
        if (files != null) {
          for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            indexDocs(writer, new File(file, files[i]));
          }
        }
      } else {

        FileInputStream fis;
        try {
          fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {

          return;
        }


        try {
          // make a new, empty document
          Document doc = new Document();



         // Field termV = new LongField("termVector", file.g) 

          Field pathField = new StringField("path", file.getPath(), Field.Store.YES);
          doc.add(pathField);
          Field modifiedField = new LongField("modified", file.lastModified(), Field.Store.NO);
          doc.add(modifiedField);
          Field titleField = new TextField("title", file.getName(), Field.Store.YES);
          doc.add(titleField);
          Field contentsField = new TextField("contents", new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
          doc.add(contentsField);
          //contentsField.setBoost((float)0.5);
          //titleField.setBoost((float)2.5);

          /* doc.add(new LongField("modified", file.lastModified(), Field.Store.NO));
          doc.add(new TextField("title", file.getName(), Field.Store.YES));

          doc.add(new TextField("contents", new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
                  */
        //  StringField..setBoost(1.2F);

          if (writer.getConfig().getOpenMode() == OpenMode.CREATE) {
            // New index, so we just add the document (no old document can be there):
            System.out.println("adding " + file);
            writer.addDocument(doc);
          } else {
            // Existing index (an old copy of this document may have been indexed) so 
            // we use updateDocument instead to replace the old one matching the exact 
            // path, if present:
            System.out.println("updating " + file);
            writer.updateDocument(new Term("path", file.getPath()), doc);
         }

        } finally {

          fis.close();
        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Tf-idf.java

```
   public class Tf_Idf {
    static float tf = 1;
    static float idf = 0;
    private float tfidf_score;
    static float [] tfidf = null;

     IndexReader indexReader;


        public Tf_Idf() throws IOException {

        this.indexReader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(new File("C:/Users/dell/Documents/NetBeansProjects/IndexingSearching/Index")));

    }
    public void scoreCalculator (String field, String term) throws IOException 
    {


        TFIDFSimilarity  tfidfSIM = new DefaultSimilarity();

        Bits liveDocs = MultiFields.getLiveDocs(indexReader);
            TermsEnum termEnum = MultiFields.getTerms(indexReader, field).iterator(null);
        BytesRef bytesRef=null;
        while ((bytesRef = termEnum.next()) != null) {
            if(bytesRef.utf8ToString().trim().equals(term.trim())) {
                if(termEnum.seekExact(bytesRef)) {
                    idf = tfidfSIM.idf(termEnum.docFreq(), indexReader.numDocs());
                    DocsEnum docsEnum = termEnum.docs(liveDocs, null);
                    if(docsEnum != null) {
                        int doc=0;
                        while((doc = docsEnum.nextDoc()) != DocIdSetIterator.NO_MORE_DOCS) {
                            tf = tfidfSIM.tf(docsEnum.freq());
                            tfidf_score = tf * idf ;
                            System.out.println(" -tfidf_score-" + tfidf_score);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: please show us where this line number is - cause we don't have this info

Comment: @Mysterion The error is in the line where I have written Correct_Me in both Doc_indexing.java and Tf_Idf.java

Comment: oh, i see. sorry, anyway please add it to question, to be clear, that you mark this error in code

Comment: which version of Lucene you use?

Comment: @Mysterion Mine is Lucene 4.8

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that you pass to *MultiFields* method a **null** *IndexReader*

```
IndexReader reader = null;
tfidf.scoreCalculator( reader, field,term);
```

You need to write something like this:

```
IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(new File(PATH_TO_LUCENE_INDEX)));
tfidf.scoreCalculator( reader, field,term);
```

You need to repalce `PATH_TO_LUCENE_INDEX` with real path, of course.

Another problem, that I see - you open `IndexReader` in Tf_Idf, but don't use it anywhere, may be it's a good idea to remove it or use it, inside of `scoreCalculator` method, e.g.

```
tfidf.scoreCalculator(field,term);
```

but in method use field of this class, - `this.indexReader` instead of just `indexReader` that you try to pass inside method `scoreCalculator`

**UPD**

```
public Tf_Idf() throws IOException {

        this.reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(new File("Index")));
    }
```

In this code, you need to replace *"Index"* with real path to your Lucene index, e.g. - `/home/user/index` or `C://index` or wherever you have it.

Comment: ok i have done the following changes
1. tfidf.scoreCalculator(field, term);
2. I am using this.indexReader inside scoreCalculator like in
Bits liveDocs = MultiFields.getLiveDocs(this.indexReader);
or
TermsEnum termEnum = MultiFields.getTerms(this.indexReader, field).iterator(null);

But there is still error in liveDocs and tfidf.scorecalculator(field,term)

Comment: because your index reader should open real index, not use fake path "Index" as I said in answer - You need to repalce PATH_TO_LUCENE_INDEX with real path, of course.

Comment: But you said me I can either use or remove it. I removed it. So I am calling the function  tfidf.scoreCalculator(field, term) with field and term only.
So where should I provide the path?

Comment: Sorry but could you tell more clearly... where should I provide the path either in tf_idf.java or doc_indexing ?

Comment: i upd answer. you should decide what to do - remove it from method or pass in method correct one index reader not null one, please pay attention to my answer, it contains all you need to fix this code

Comment: I did that still it is not resolved. I have also edited my code as per the changes you told me. Please see once.

Comment: what's the problem now? if you use index reader in Tf-idf class, you should remove index reader from here public void scoreCalculator (IndexReader indexReader,String field, String term) throws IOException 
    {

Comment: 2 errors. Firstly in  TermsEnum termEnum = MultiFields.getTerms(indexReader, field).iterator(null); and Secondly in   tfidf.scoreCalculator(field, term); . Sorry for the trouble. But this is my project so I am very grateful for your help

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(TreeMap.java:342)
 at java.util.TreeMap.get(TreeMap.java:273)
 at org.apache.lucene.codecs.perfield.PerFieldPostingsFormat$FieldsReader.terms(PerFieldPostingsFormat.java:216)
 at org.apache.lucene.index.MultiFields.getTerms(MultiFields.java:131)
 at Lucene.Tf_Idf.scoreCalculator(Tf_Idf.java:54)
 at Lucene.DocIndexing.main(DocIndexing.java:115)

Comment: yes, this is because you pass 2 nulls for term and a field ,for sure it will be a  NPE

Comment: So how do I resolve it. I had asked this as my 1st question where I had pointed with Correct_Me

Comment: I know that but you have seen my code so please could you tell me exactly what value should I pass ?